# C# ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized does not work for PSR.exe

Tags: c#, minimize

Gurus,

I am struggling with a basic function in C#. I am not a develop expert, but I want to develop a PoC for a given customer requirement. Your guidance is welcome.

I am using the following peace of code, however, it is not working as expected.

I want to open psr.exe minimized, but looks like the windows style has been ignored.

```
ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo("psr.exe");
proc.Arguments = "/start /output ....;
proc.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
proc.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process.Start(proc);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try changing it to `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`

Comment: @MethodMan thanks for your answer. I've tried, but I got the same result. The psr window is still showing up.

Comment: then do a google search on the following `C# stackoverflow RedirectStandardOutput` plenty of good working examples.

Comment: `UseShellExecute = false` probably is the problem. Setting it to true is to use the OS shell to start the application

Comment: My previous comment was incorrect, I meant to say "it works if `UseShellExecute=true`, but you can't redirect output with that setting". If you don't need the output then just do that. Another option is to use the dllImport [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/779ccb93-c9cd-49a5-881b-9218cbdf3aa5/minimize-a-systemdiagnosticsprocess?forum=csharpgeneral), where you need `var theProcess = Process.Start()` then `ShowWindow(theProcess.MainWindowHandle, 2)`; you have to `Thread.Sleep(some amount of time)` to wait for it the main window to be available, though.

Comment: Thank you all for the guidance. Actually, I've tried all recommendations and it still not working in C#. Also, I tried in another language such as js.net and it works. Perhaps, it is something in my workstation or something like that.

Here is the solution I founded.

I've added an additional argument "/gui 0" and psr has opened with no windows. 

Again thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use shellExecute true and run the application with admin privilges,

```
string fileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\RequiredApp.exe";
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.Arguments = null;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
process.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
process.Start();
```

Comment: Redirect Outputs wont work if ShellExecute is true, and the OP seems to need that